# What Python function could i use to find the greatest common divisor of three numbers?

Tags: python, python-2.7, math

I've attempted to use included functions as well as attempting to write my own, but unfortunately i was unsuccessful. Hopefully someone more experienced than myself has run into this issue and come up with a solution.

Comment: How about the `gcd` function from Python's `fractions` module? `gcd(a, gcd(b, c))` gives you the greatest common divisor of `a`, `b` and `c`.

Comment: Or more generally, `reduce(fractions.gcd, list_of_numbers)`.

Comment: @MasonAlphonse, welcome to stackoverflow. As you see, your question has been asked before so it's in the process of being marked as a duplicate. Look there for the answer (hint: Don't just look at the accepted answer-- the next one is more useful).